# DHCP Lease Renew Issues with Intel NUC using CentOS 7

Tags: centos, dhcp

I am seeing the following activity in my /var/log/messages file that seems to happen every night at 02:58.

The issue is that sometimes the machine comes back online and sometimes it does not.

What is going on here and how I make it stop?

```
Jan 9 02:58:35 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
Jan 9 02:58:35 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020715.3198] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jan 9 02:58:35 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020715.4139] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <warn> [1547020730.8682] device (wlp58s0): link timed out.
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020730.8696] device (wlp58s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020730.8715] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <warn> [1547020730.8805] device (wlp58s0): Activation: failed for connection 'crawdaddy18'
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 dbus[4788]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020730.8849] device (wlp58s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp58s0: link is not ready
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 systemd: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020730.8950] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 5333
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020730.8951] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): state changed bound -> done
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020730.8980] dhcp6 (wlp58s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 6016
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020730.8981] dhcp6 (wlp58s0): state changed bound -> done
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020730.9029] device (wlp58s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 8A:D5:03:72:AA:7D (scanning)
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp58s0: link is not ready
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020730.9195] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020730.9231] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 dbus[4788]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 systemd: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp58s0]: new request (3 scripts)
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp58s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': new request (3 scripts)
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 chronyd[4841]: Source 208.75.88.4 offline
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 chronyd[4841]: Source 69.10.161.7 offline
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 chronyd[4841]: Source 72.14.183.239 offline
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 chronyd[4841]: Source 52.6.160.3 offline
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 chronyd[4841]: Can't synchronise: no selectable sources
Jan 9 02:58:50 mapr04 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Jan 9 03:01:01 mapr04 systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
Jan 9 03:01:01 mapr04 systemd: Started Session 341 of user root.
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5171] policy: auto-activating connection 'crawdaddy18' (c3747559-0a8f-4c9f-b9f8-1333e55f8338)
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5200] device (wlp58s0): Activation: starting connection 'crawdaddy18' (c3747559-0a8f-4c9f-b9f8-1333e55f8338)
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5205] device (wlp58s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5216] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5253] device (wlp58s0): set-hw-addr: set-cloned MAC address to F8:94:C2:5C:07:24 (permanent)
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp58s0: link is not ready
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5309] device (wlp58s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5319] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'crawdaddy18' has security, but secrets are required.

Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5319] device (wlp58s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5327] sup-iface[0x5561c7748a40,wlp58s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5376] device (wlp58s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5386] device (wlp58s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5390] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'crawdaddy18' has security, and secrets exist. No new secrets needed.
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5391] Config: added 'ssid' value 'crawdaddy18'
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5391] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5391] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5391] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5391] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5391] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5409] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> disconnected
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5497] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jan 9 03:01:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020885.5552] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: authenticate with 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: send auth to 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a (try 1/3)
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020887.0172] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: authenticated
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: associate with 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a (try 1/3)
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a (capab=0x1531 status=0 aid=2)
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020887.0287] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associaing
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: associated
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020887.0344] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp58s0: link becomes ready
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020887.0531] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020887.0532] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network 'crawdaddy18'.
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020887.0533] device (wlp58s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020887.0538] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020887.0564] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): dhclient started with pid 14402
Jan 9 03:01:27 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPREQUEST on wlp58s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xb260c2f)
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPREQUEST on wlp58s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xb260c2f)
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPNAK from 192.168.1.250 (xid=0xb260c2f)
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.2291] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): state changed unknown -> expire
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.2444] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): state changed expire -> unknown
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp58s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x22a3f888)
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPREQUEST on wlp58s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x22a3f888)
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPOFFER from 192.168.1.250
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPACK from 192.168.1.250 (xid=0x22a3f888)
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6010] dhcp4 (wlp58s0):  address 192.168.1.139
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6011] dhcp4 (wlp58s0):  plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6011] dhcp4 (wlp58s0):  gateway 192.168.1.250
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6011] dhcp4 (wlp58s0):  lease time 60
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6012] dhcp4 (wlp58s0):  nameserver '192.168.1.250'
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6012] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6046] device (wlp58s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: bound to 192.168.1.139 -- renewal in 29 seconds.
Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6079] device (wlp58s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6088] device (wlp58s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6100] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6206] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6212] policy: set 'crawdaddy18' (wlp58s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6267] device (wlp58s0): Activation: successful, device activated.

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020892.6291] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 dbus[4788]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 systemd: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 dbus[4788]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 systemd: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [wlp58s0]: new request (3 scripts)

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [wlp58s0]: start running ordered scripts...

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': new request (3 scripts)

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 chronyd[4841]: Source 72.14.183.239 online

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 chronyd[4841]: Source 52.6.160.3 online

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 chronyd[4841]: Source 69.10.161.7 online

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 chronyd[4841]: Source 208.75.88.4 online

Jan 9 03:01:32 mapr04 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...

Jan 9 03:01:33 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020893.5095] dhcp6 (wlp58s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)

Jan 9 03:01:33 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020893.5140] dhcp6 (wlp58s0): dhclient started with pid 14455

Jan 9 03:01:33 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020893.5175] policy: set 'crawdaddy18' (wlp58s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS

Jan 9 03:01:34 mapr04 dhclient[14455]: XMT: Confirm on wlp58s0, interval 1090ms.

Jan 9 03:01:35 mapr04 dhclient[14455]: XMT: Confirm on wlp58s0, interval 2150ms.

Jan 9 03:01:35 mapr04 dhclient[14455]: RCV: Reply message on wlp58s0 from fe80::7203:7eff:fe4c:dc09.

Jan 9 03:01:35 mapr04 dhclient[14455]: message status code Success: "Your addresses are correct for this link! Yay!"

Jan 9 03:01:35 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020895.4539] dhcp6 (wlp58s0):  valid_lft 604800

Jan 9 03:01:35 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020895.4539] dhcp6 (wlp58s0):  preferred_lft 604800

Jan 9 03:01:35 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020895.4540] dhcp6 (wlp58s0):  address 2601:143:580:67::d80f

Jan 9 03:01:35 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020895.4540] dhcp6 (wlp58s0):  nameserver '2001:558:feed::1'

Jan 9 03:01:35 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020895.4540] dhcp6 (wlp58s0):  nameserver '2001:558:feed::2'

Jan 9 03:01:35 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020895.4540] dhcp6 (wlp58s0): state changed unknown -> bound, event ID="c2:5c:07:24|1546873502"

Jan 9 03:01:35 mapr04 nm-dispatcher: req:3 'dhcp6-change' [wlp58s0]: new request (3 scripts)

Jan 9 03:01:35 mapr04 nm-dispatcher: req:3 'dhcp6-change' [wlp58s0]: start running ordered scripts...

Jan 9 03:02:01 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPREQUEST on wlp58s0 to 192.168.1.250 port 67 (xid=0x22a3f888)

Jan 9 03:02:06 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPREQUEST on wlp58s0 to 192.168.1.250 port 67 (xid=0x22a3f888)

Jan 9 03:02:12 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPREQUEST on wlp58s0 to 192.168.1.250 port 67 (xid=0x22a3f888)

Jan 9 03:02:24 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPREQUEST on wlp58s0 to 192.168.1.250 port 67 (xid=0x22a3f888)

Jan 9 03:02:31 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPREQUEST on wlp58s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x22a3f888)

Jan 9 03:02:32 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: disassociated from 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)

Jan 9 03:02:32 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)

Jan 9 03:02:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <warn> [1547020952.0471] sup-iface[0x5561c7748a40,wlp58s0]: connection disconnected (reason 1)

Jan 9 03:02:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020952.0523] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected

Jan 9 03:02:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020952.1526] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Jan 9 03:02:33 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020953.4112] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): state changed bound -> expire

Jan 9 03:02:33 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020953.4112] device (wlp58s0): DHCPv4: 480 seconds grace period started

Jan 9 03:02:33 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020953.4152] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): state changed expire -> unknown

Jan 9 03:02:33 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp58s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x3591c1e3)

Jan 9 03:02:33 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: authenticate with 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12

Jan 9 03:02:33 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: send auth to 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12 (try 1/3)

Jan 9 03:02:33 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020953.6207] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Jan 9 03:02:33 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: authenticated

Jan 9 03:02:33 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: associate with 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12 (try 1/3)

Jan 9 03:02:33 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)

Jan 9 03:02:33 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: associated

Jan 9 03:02:33 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020953.6321] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associated

Jan 9 03:02:33 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020953.6557] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp58s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x3591c1e3)

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPREQUEST on wlp58s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3591c1e3)

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPOFFER from 192.168.1.1

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: DHCPACK from 192.168.1.1 (xid=0x3591c1e3)

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020957.7885] dhcp4 (wlp58s0):  address 192.168.1.101

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020957.7886] dhcp4 (wlp58s0):  plen 24 (255.255.255.0)

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020957.7886] dhcp4 (wlp58s0):  gateway 192.168.1.1

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020957.7887] dhcp4 (wlp58s0):  lease time 604800

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020957.7887] dhcp4 (wlp58s0):  hostname 'mapr04'

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020957.7887] dhcp4 (wlp58s0):  nameserver '75.75.75.75'

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020957.7887] dhcp4 (wlp58s0):  nameserver '75.75.76.76'

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020957.7887] dhcp4 (wlp58s0):  domain name 'hsd1.va.comcast.net'

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020957.7888] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): state changed unknown -> bound

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547020957.7925] policy: set 'crawdaddy18' (wlp58s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 dbus[4788]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 dhclient[14402]: bound to 192.168.1.101 -- renewal in 288098 seconds.

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 systemd: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 dbus[4788]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 systemd: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp58s0]: new request (3 scripts)

Jan 9 03:02:37 mapr04 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp58s0]: start running ordered scripts...

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: disassociated from 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <warn> [1547021005.5051] sup-iface[0x5561c7748a40,wlp58s0]: connection disconnected (reason 2)

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021005.5106] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021005.6109] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: authenticate with 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: send auth to 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a (try 1/3)

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021005.6559] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: authenticated

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: associate with 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a (try 1/3)

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a (capab=0x1531 status=0 aid=2)

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021005.6630] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: associated

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021005.6692] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021005.7097] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: deauthenticated from 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a (Reason: 5=DISASSOC_AP_BUSY)

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <warn> [1547021005.7879] sup-iface[0x5561c7748a40,wlp58s0]: connection disconnected (reason 5)

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021005.8009] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021005.8932] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: authenticate with 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12

Jan 9 0:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: send auth to 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12 (try 1/3)
Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: authenticated
Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021005.9253] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: associate with 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12 (try 1/3)
Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: associated
Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021005.9378] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated

Jan 9 03:03:25 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021005.9699] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed

Jan 9 03:03:31 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: disassociated from 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
Jan 9 03:03:31 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
Jan 9 03:03:31 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <warn> [1547021011.5827] sup-iface[0x5561c7748a40,wlp58s0]: connection disconnected (reason 2)
Jan 9 03:03:31 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021011.5883] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected

Jan 9 03:03:31 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021011.6885] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Jan 9 03:03:31 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: authenticate with 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a
Jan 9 03:03:31 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: send auth to 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a (try 1/3)
Jan 9 03:03:31 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021011.7362] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 9 03:03:31 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: send auth to 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a (try 2/3)
Jan 9 03:03:31 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: send auth to 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a (try 3/3)
Jan 9 03:03:32 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: authentication with 70:03:7e:4c:dc:0a timed out
Jan 9 03:03:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021012.0812] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jan 9 03:03:32 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021012.1814] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 9 03:03:34 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: authenticate with 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12
Jan 9 03:03:34 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: send auth to 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12 (try 1/3)
Jan 9 03:03:34 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021014.5980] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 9 03:03:34 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: authenticated
Jan 9 03:03:34 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: associate with 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12 (try 1/3)
Jan 9 03:03:34 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from 70:03:7e:4c:dc:12 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=3)
Jan 9 03:03:34 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021014.6061] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 9 03:03:34 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: associated
Jan 9 03:03:34 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021014.6124] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jan 9 03:03:34 mapr04 NetworkManager[4849]: <info> [1547021014.6462] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed
Jan 9 03:13:24 mapr04 chronyd[4841]: Selected source 52.6.160.3
Jan 9 03:23:02 mapr04 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

1) It looks like you are using a wireless access and whatever kernel you are using disables that interface completely at some point:

```
    kernel: wlp58s0: failed to remove key
```

2) Then it tries to identify the hardware and connect to the ssid, but it cannot find SSID:

```
    failed (reason 'ssid-not-found')
```

3) And then it connects normally to the access point.

---

What might be wrong here?
A few things actually:

a. What is our OS and kernel version? Have you tried to upgrade to a recent kernel?

b. What your wireless AP says during that time period? It might be the case that your access point reboots causing the following behavior on your linux machine.

c. Have you tried replacing wireless adapter? Does this happen over the physical (wired) link?

The most concerning error out of all the log file is:

```
Jan 9 03:02:32 mapr04 kernel: wlp58s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
```

You should look out for that. Maybe try finding the answer here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/967441/17-1-wlp6s0-failed-to-remove-key-1-ffffffffffff-from-hardware-22